# My review progress has been deleted after the recent change of review UI

Tags: bug, review-queues

I had a progress of > 800 post reviews until yesterday and was looking forward to get my first golden badge. After the recent change of review UI (it looked like the one of askubuntu.com for some hours yesterday) this progress seems gone. it is 1 for Late answers and 38 for First posts.

Comment: Which review queue did you have 800 reviews in?

Comment: I never spotted a difference because numbers where going up and I was watching it quite closely because of the reward of the golden badge approaching. I think there has been "triage" as only review option for so with my reputation.

Comment: Side note: Only pick "Requires Editing" when the edits can be done by someone other than the OP. Clicking "Requires Editing" sends it into a different queue, and someone has to spend one of their 20 reviews on it. What would I be able to do to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9964760) to make it clear? Don't take this as me saying that you're doing it wrong every time. Just asking that you please be careful.

Comment: Since you say below that the bug no longer occurs, I've voted to close this report as irreproducible. If it happens again, please let us know.

Comment: Now the review progress is gone again (and the review UI changed again to be like on askubuntu.com). "First posts" is at 46 (was almost 900 before) and "Late answers" is at 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the review progress is back.

Comment: I assume you mean [this one, from triage](http://stackoverflow.com/review/user-info/10/1797006), you are now at 900 reviews

Comment: I guess it wasn't visible for some moments and I mixed up the queues assuming the progress was gone...